# What is the resource server?

Tags: php, codeigniter, oauth-2.0

I am using the fantastic Oauth2 server library from Alex Bilbie. It works perfectly fine but I am not sure how to use the Resource Server. What is that?

https://github.com/alexbilbie/CodeIgniter-OAuth-2.0-Server/blob/master/libraries/Oauth_resource_server.php

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the specs [draft-25 section 1.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-25#section-1.1):

> *resource server*: The server hosting the protected resources, capable of accepting and responding to protected resource requests using access tokens.

So, a resource server, can be any application (usually an API) with functions that requires `OAuth authenticated access`.

Comment: I am not sure how to use it with Alex Bilbies library. Do you?